# Rounding in SQL

Tags: sql

I am using

```
1234 / (CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), PAM10501.HOURSWKD) / 60)
```

calculation. This `convert` function still is showing 4 decimal places. I tried other way

```
round(PAM10501.HOURSWKD) / 60, 2)
```

then I am getting value like 3.00 instead of 3.87683. What is easiest way to get value like 3.87?

Comment: Hard to test without knowing the SQL dialect, but `ROUND(PAM10501.HOURSWKD / 60.0, 2)` would make sense. Dividing by the integer `60` will probably result in an integer, so you need to divide by `60.0` instead.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That divide by float trick is not required on some databases, e.g. MySQL.  We won't know for certain unless the OP tags properly.

Comment: how about this one ? select CAST(round(PAM10501.HOURSWKD/ 60.00, 2) as decimal(10,2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to cast the decimal's into 2 places.

```
select CAST(round(PAM10501.HOURSWKD/ 60.00, 2) as decimal(10,2))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is working for me